# time data '2020-07-06 10:52:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %X'

Tags: python

when i'm using time.strptime to format a time str, it always raise the error below

```
time data '2020-07-06 10:52:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %X'
```

stack info

```
  File "_strptime.py", line 571, in _strptime_time
  File "_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
```

could anyone gives me some tips?

environment:

> os: macos 10.14.5
> python version: 3.7.0

Comment: `format` is the current format, not the format you want it to be. You're probably looking for `pandas.Series.dt.strftime`

Comment: both `time.strptime('2020-07-06 10:52:00', '%Y-%m-%d %X')` and `datetime.strptime('2020-07-06 10:52:00', '%Y-%m-%d %X')` work for me

Comment: You should include complete stack trace to get a concrete answer.

Comment: your format is '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: @VigneshRajendran yes, i should change my time format 2 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'.though '%Y-%m-%d %X' test ok when in python script, but it went wrong after i use pyinstaller to frozen my program. but i don't know what is the differcence between them.

Comment: its due to x is for representing Locale’s appropriate time representation. this will check PC Region settings. if you use  %H:%M:%S, this will work straight away.